# Distillery release fails: Could not locate code path for m{elixir-1.7.2","./lib/elixir-1.7.2

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, distillery

I'm trying to deploy my application on Gigalixir, following the getting started with an existing app.

I have added `[{:distillery, "~> 2.1"}]` to my mix.deps

building the release for production

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE="$(mix phx.gen.secret)" 
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/rumbl_dev"
MIX_ENV=prod
mix distillery.release --env=prod
```

But then I run `_build/prod/rel/rumbl/bin/rumbl start`, and that fails with

```
Could not locate code path for m{elixir-1.7.2","./lib/elixir-1.7.2!
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare elixir version in your mix file and version installed at the server.

Comment: For anyone with this same problem, :app_name/mix.exs in `def project`, the elixir definition was different than what was in the elixir build pack

Comment: @EricProstko [**and the future visitors**]: `project` section in `mix.exs` specifies the _minimal_ not the _exact_ requirement for [tag:elixir] version.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, the command "unset GREP_OPTIONS" solved this issue for me. I found this issue is relevant to the wrong return value of function __rel_apps() in phoenix/{your-app}/_build/prod/rel/{your-app}/releases/{your-version}/libexec/erts.sh. Then, the solution is referenced from underlying link.

https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/issues/592